# Cypress: Unable to install binary file

Tags: node.js, cypress

I'm trying to install cypress using binary. Currently using below command in vs code: `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\cypress.zip npm install cypress`

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress.html#Install-binary

This is not working for me, showing below error:

```
CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\cypress.zip : The term 'CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\cypress.zip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\cypress.zip npm ins ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CYPRESS_INSTALL...ads\cypress.zip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Can anyone help me to fix this please?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try another two methods by following docs?

Comment: Option 1: I don't want to install conflicting binary version. Option 2: Can't bypass corporate firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Below steps worked for me;

- Download cypress binary file
- Create `.npmrc` in your working directory
- Add this to `.npmrc` file: `CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=\your\path\to\cypress.x.x.x.zip`
- Running `npm install cypress` after these steps will install cypress from the binary file

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work...by setting UNIX like a path on windows cmd

`SET CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=C:/Users/myUserName/Downloads/cypress.zip`

Comment: This is not the answer. You posted the same thing from the given link. My question was option 3 is throw error so how to fix it?

Comment: Could you check this issue on [Github](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/761)

Comment: The very last part of this answer, where you used forward slashes instead of backward slashes helped me.  The most frustrating part of this is now you don't get any errors if it fails to read your path.  It just competes as if everything went fine.  No error in the logs either.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with several npm commands:

```
    "e2e": "npm run e2e:installcypress && npm run e2e:run && npm run e2e:coverage",
    "e2e:installcypress": "CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=/path/to/cypress.zip npm install cypress",
    "e2e:run": "ng e2e",
    "e2e:coverage": "npx nyc report --reporter=lcov --reporter=html",
```

Now npm run e2e does all 3

Answer (score 0):

Try This -

```
set CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY=\your\path\to\cypress.x.x.x.zip

npm install cypress

npx cypress open
```

Comment: If you want to use electron by default -> `npx cypress run --headed`

Comment: or `npx cypress open` and select electron browser to execute the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you have proxy issues while installing cypress. This helps.
   Download cypress.zip from https://download.cypress.io/desktop.json
   Create a latest version folder (e.g., 12.12.0) and place extracted zip there.
   Run npm install cypress --save-dev & npx cypress open

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: These instructions are not completely clear.  Do I run npm install cypress in my latest folder or switch back to my project folder?  If in my project folder, what should I be setting CYPRESS_INSTALL_BINARY to?